# Flutter - Tab title overflow in Convex Bottom Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, convex-bottom-bar

I am trying to use convex_bottom_bar lib, but when I try using a slightly longer title for a tab, it overflows. In the image below I tried to use the title Notifications, but it overflowed by 1 letter. I searched for solutions to this problem but I couldn't find any. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: You need to share your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package.

```
AutoSizeText(
  'Notifications',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
  minFontSize: 15,
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // If you want to show ... after text like notifica...
)
```

Comment: This lib does not work too. The title is placed inside TabItem, like this: TabItem(
            icon: Icons.notifications,
            title: "Notifications"
          )  I can only use strings for title

Comment: So for that, wrap your tab inside container and give width to it as per your requirement.